Reloading routes return 404 for Azure Static Web Apps
Before i begin i have seen this question and it does not solve my problem
I have a react app that uses azure static web apps i wanted to modify the app to support old versions of the app. so i did the following

build app
upload new build files to azure blob storage overwriting and existing files
download all files from blob
deploy to azure static web apps

here's the workflow steps in guthub action
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: "18"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build TypeScript
        run: npm run build

      # Merge new assets with existing assets in azure storage overwriting existing files
      - name: Upload assets to Azure Blob storage
        uses: azure/CLI@v2
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            az storage blob upload-batch --account-name ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} --account-key ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY }} --destination ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME }} --source dist --pattern "*" --destination-path "" --overwrite

      # Download all assets from Azure Blob storage
      - name: Download assets from Azure Blob storage
        uses: azure/CLI@v2
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            mkdir -p ${{github.workspace}}/new
            az storage blob download-batch --account-name ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} --account-key ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY }} --destination  ${{github.workspace}}/new --source ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME }}

      # Show all files in the new folder after download (for logging purposes)
      - name: Show files in /new folder
        run: ls ${{github.workspace}}/new

      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_MANGO_BAY_0BBC9890F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "${{github.workspace}}/new" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional
          skip_app_build: true
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

im using the new folder to store the files so i can store the files from blob to be uploaded into static web apps
My issue starts here in my react app i have a file staticwebapp.config.json with
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}

this is not working, which makes sense to me since im using the /new folder instead of the app default folder the config is not read and therefore i have this issue, Im not sure how i can modify to get this config to work if i go back to my original workflow where i just deploy to azure static web apps without the blob storage everything works correctly
Thanks in Advance!

Can you share your github repo if possible ?

@SirraSneha i cannot its private, sorry

So here's what i came up with. Since i am specifying in the app_location to look in the /new folder i need to add the staticwebapp.config.json file to the /new folder.
I have 2 options

copying it over from app dir to the new folder (I tried that but it didn't work gave me permission error)
Manually adding the file to azure blob storage container.

The second option worked fine for me, but i now have to remember if i ever need to change the config file to go and change it there which is less then ideal.
Summary: this solution is not something i would do long term just something i found that works so i wanted to mention
